# Do I need separate VIP for my sub-domains?

Tags: docker, load-balancing, artifactory, f5

We are going to have multiple domains in our environment

Main URL is : maven-qa.xx.com

sub-domains would be : docker-local.maven-qa.xx.com , docker-registry.maven-qa.xx.com, docker.io.maven-qa.xx.com etc

To resolve this we have got wildcard certs *.maven-qa.xx.com

My question is : Do we need to create separate VIPS to make it work OR just a DNS entry *.maven-qa.xx.com Load-balancer-ip would be enough

The request is going through load balancer

I asked this because I am getting below error when i am pulling from artifactory

```
root@vagrant:~# docker pull docker-registry.maven-qa.xx.com/busybox:latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://docker-registry.maven-qa.xx.com/v2/: dial tcp 10.29.xxx.xx:443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need a VIP for each sub-domain.

I have a VIP with HAProxy (tcpmode) pointing to a Artifactory PRO 2 node cluster. Each node in the cluster runs nginx + artifactory. I use a wildcard cert for *.sjcartifactory.xxx.nimblestorage.com. Our docker repo is accessed via docker.sjcartifactory.xxx.nimblestorage.com. In DNS there is an entry of docker.sjcartifactory.xxx.nimblestorage.com being a CNAME of sjcartifactory.xxx.nimblestorage.com.

I would guess the issue is your proxy setup rather than your LB. Unless you're using your LB as your proxy such as HAProxy in httpmode?